# Does always int i{0} be faster then int i = 0?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, compiler-optimization

```
int i{0}; //(1)
int i = 0; //(2)
```

Do I have correct understanding that in first case (1) the variable i will be created already with 0 as it's value, and in (2) it will be created without a value and then assigned a value 0, so (1) will always faster then (2)?

But seems like most(all?) modern compilers will still optimize (2) to be same as (1) under the hood?

Comment: Is 1 in the question a typo?

Comment: No, here they ultimately mean the same thing.  Space is allocated for `i` and that space is immediately zeroed. No assignment involved. [See here for documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)

Comment: No, the code will be the same: there's no reason for the compiler to generate slower code with extra assignment. `i` can't be created without value

Comment: [Excellent viewing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs)  if you have an hour and really want to get deep into C++ initialization.

Comment: there is no assigment in your code

Comment: @user4581301: Or if you want to know how to look at the asm and answer the question for yourself, Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk [“What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4) shows how.  
 (also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116))

Comment: @PeterCordes  Looks like I upvoted the linked question and answer at some point in the past. May not have watched the video, so I've mailed the link to myself to remind me later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

initializing variables with Brace Initialization performs additional checks at compile time (no effect on runtime). . Such as if you enter a float literal inside the curly braces it will throw an error. Initialization with the equal sign will be optimized by the compiler. Prefer brace initialization whenever possible. I hope that answers your question